# Microphone Picks up Desktop Audio not my voice

Tags: sound, microphone

I've had this problem that my mic is picking up my Desktop sound for like 5 days I've tried many possible ways to fix that. But nothing, so my last resort was to ask some of you guys 4 help.

(I'm not a Linux pro xd)